# Parse json array into Python list

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7, list

I have created my own json data with an array I would like to parse into a python list. However, I've been having trouble doing so.

How can I extract my json array into a python list?

json data:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "192.168.241.109", 
    "cameras": 
       {
          "front": "nf091", 
          "inside": "nf067", 
          "right": "004317",
          "rear": "000189",
          "left": "nf084"
       }
  }, 
  {
   "ip": "192.168.241.110",           
   "cameras": 
   {
          "front": "nf091", 
          "inside": "nf067", 
          "right": "004317", 
          "rear": "000189", 
          "left": "nf084"
   }
  }
]
```

My json data is valid, so I don't know why I'm having trouble with the below code:

```
system_json = open(json_file)
json_obj = json.load(system_json)

camera_details = [[i['front'], i['rear'], i['left'], i['right'], i['inside']] for i in json_obj['cameras']]
```

The above code snippet does not work as it yields the `list indices must be integers, not str` error.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I properly parse my json array into a python list?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that your JSON "object" is a list, but then you try to index into it with a string (`json_obj['cameras']`).

What you have is a JSON array, each element of which is a dictionary containing (among other things) a key called `"cameras"`. I believe this code does what you want:

```
import json

text = """[{"ip": "192.168.241.109", "cameras": {"front": "nf091", "inside": "nf067", "right": "004317", "rear": "000189", "left": "nf084"}}, {"ip": "192.168.241.110", "cameras": {"front": "nf091", "inside": "nf067", "right": "004317", "rear": "000189", "left": "nf084"}}]"""

json_array = json.loads(text)

camera_details = [[i['cameras']['front'], i['cameras']['rear'], i['cameras']['left'], i['cameras']['right'], i['cameras']['inside']] for i in json_array]
print(camera_details)

# Output:
# [['nf091', '000189', 'nf084', '004317', 'nf067'], ['nf091', '000189', 'nf084', '004317', 'nf067']]
```

**EDIT**

Possibly clearer/easier?

```
camera_details = [
    [
        cameras["front"],
        cameras["rear"],
        cameras["left"],
        cameras["right"],
        cameras["inside"],
    ]
    for cameras in [item["cameras"] for item in json_array]
]
```